# SIGNAL SQLSTATE inside UPDATE CASE

Tags: sql, triggers, db2, sql-update

I cannot try the TRIGGER on the field and I have a question. I've tried looking for an answer without success. Well, is it possible to put a "SIGNAL SQLSTATE..." inside an UPDATE CASE of DB2 TRIGGER?

For example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T1
[...]
BEGIN ATOMIC

UPDATE Table
  SET column = 
    CASE
      WHEN [...] 
        THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70000' ('ERROR')
      ELSE 
[...]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Putting it in as a _result-expression_ in a _CASE expression_ would mean that you want to set _column_ to be equal to `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70000' ('ERROR')`. And that makes no sense at all.

Comment: Right! I think this is an acceptable answer. Thank you.

Comment: @user2338816 Please write an answer with what you wrote as comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *CASE-expression* can't execute a statement inside an UPDATE statement. It only returns a *result-value*. If you want to execute a statement such as `SIGNAL SQLSTATE...`, I suppose you might use it like this (not recommended and not tested):

```
IF ( CASE WHEN [...condition] THEN true ELSE false END )
   THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70000' ('ERROR') ;
   ELSE UPDATE Table  SET column = [...value] ;
```

However, it's probably better simply to do it like this:

```
IF ( [...condition] )
   THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '70000' ('ERROR') ;
   ELSE UPDATE Table  SET column = [...value] ;
```

Without more detail on exactly what is intended, it's hard to be sure what is needed.